# IndexedDB error Unhandled rejection: AbortError: Transaction aborted

Tags: angular, indexeddb, dexie

I am a trying to save a JSON object in IndexedDB with Dexie:

```
      var db = new Dexie ("List",);

      db.version(2).stores({
        list2: "++id,name",
        Itemslist: JSON.stringify(this.AllItems)
        });
      
        
      db.open().then(result => {
      }).catch(e => {
      console.log("error: " + e);
      });
```

Getting this error in Chrome console:

```
Unhandled rejection: AbortError: Transaction aborted
```

The array 'this.AllItems' has 80MB of data.

How can I Fix the error?

Comment: Break up the operation into multiple transactions with smaller amounts of data so that you are less likely to run into some kind of undocumented timeout or hit some kind of undocumented memory cap

Comment: This is a good idea, however, if I divide the array, for example by ten 'JSON.stringify(this.AllItems.splice(0,Math.ceil(this.AllItems.length / 10)));'  I get 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')' though if iI do 'console.log()' to the spliced array it clearly shows it is not empty.